# Angular ng-repeat not working on element

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `input type="number"`:

```
<input type="number"
ng-model="question.numberOfLines" min="1" max="5" />
```

I logged the ng-model on the console and it gives me a number so I know it's working. Now I want to repeat an `<hr />` element the amount of times equal to the variable I previously mentioned, but it doesn't work. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<hr class="question-line" ng-repeat="lines in question.numberOfLines" />
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can you do an `ng-repeat` on a single number?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `ng-repeat` with collections. You are trying to use with integer.

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

In this case, you can create an `new Array(number)` and iterate over this.

Inside your **controller**:

```
$scope.myArrayNumber = new Array($scope.question.numberOfLines);
```

And inside your **View**:

```
<hr class="question-line" ng-repeat="lines in myArrayNumber " />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using *ng-repeat* correctly.

*ng-repeat* is expecting an array.

Let's say we have this code:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('sample', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.question = {
    lines: [1,2,3],
    numberOfLines: 3,
  };  
}]);
```

Then you must use *ng-repeat* as following:

```
<hr class="question-line" ng-repeat="line in question.lines" />
```

You can see it working in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bVkSJC88FeoOZBsgTC11)